# Tableau substring

Tags: substring, tableau-api

I am not sure how to use the `mid` function.

This is the account number

```
10010730000091
```

and I want to do `Substring(Account_Id, 4, 6)` in Tableau. Basically I need the six numbers from the fourth position.

Comment: Which language ? From the function name I would say it's an Office Excel thing, but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

`MID` syntax in Tableau: MID(string, start, length[optional])

```
MID(Account_Id, 4, 6)
```